# SVG text with specific width and height

Tags: php, vector, svg

I'm trying to place and stretch text in a SVG, in this example, I wanted the text to have a 4cm height but it seems it has some padding around!

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10cm" height="10cm">
 <text x="0cm" y="4cm" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="4cm">Random text</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

How to remove the padding and set the text to have exactly 4cm of height?
If not possible in SVG, is there another vector graphics format that's easy to generate with php and can perform this task?

Comment: You mean the [ascender](http://www.fontshop.com/glossary/) is 4cm high? [`<text>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) has only `textLength` and `lengthAdjust` attribute, so adjusting `font-size="151pt"` comes closest to 4cm high

Answer (score 3):

How much of the height the text fills, will depend on how the font was designed.  In your example, the 'H' doesn't extend the full height of the "em" measurement.  there will be glyphs that reach below the baseline (like 'y','g' etc) and glyphs that reach higher (eg. accents).

You can compensate by choosing a font-size that is larger then the vertical size you want.  The ratio of  font-size to rendered height should be constant for a specific font.  So once you work out the right ratio, you can use it for any text.

For example, look at the following example

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="20cm" height="20cm" font-family="Arial">

  <!-- text to fit 4cm high rectangle -->
  <rect x="0" y="1cm" width="100%" height="4cm" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.2"/>
  <text x="0cm" y="5cm" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="4cm">
      <tspan font-size="1.4em">Random text</tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
```

I want to make the text fill the height of the red rectangle.  I start by setting the font-size to 4cm, then use a `<tspan>` to bump the font size to 1.4em.  For Arial, this the ratio between the height of capitals and the em size. I found this just by experimentation.

Now I know this ratio, I can use it again for a different font size:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="20cm" height="20cm" font-family="Arial">

  <!-- text to fit 3cm high rectangle -->
  <rect x="0" y="7cm" width="100%" height="3cm" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.2"/>
  <text x="0cm" y="10cm" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="3cm">
      <tspan font-size="1.4em">Random text</tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
```

I've changed the font size to 3cm, but I can reuse the 1.4 ratio to make it fit the new size.

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m85ts8sn/1/)

Unfortunately this trick only works for height, which is constant for a particular font size.  There is no easy way to make a piece of text fit a particular width.  Other than applying a custom `transform`, or tinkering with `font-size-adjust` for each piece of text.

Comment: Thank you, it adds a lot to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the padding, the **dx** attribute controls the location of the text inside the SVG object.

Like this:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10cm" height="5.5cm" style="background: #ace; fill: #579;">

   <text dx="-0.3cm" x="0cm" y="4cm" font-family="Arial" font-size="4cm">Hello</text>

</svg>
```

Note that the dx attribute is set to **-0.3cm** which moved the text to the left.

Comment: The text is actually dynamic! And the problem is I can't use a script to calculate anything since i'm generating the svg from PHP and embedding it in a PDF!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I could come up with

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px" style="background: #EEE">
    <text x="0" y="0" style="dominant-baseline: hanging;font-size:500px"
    textLength="100%" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

There's still the margin on the bottom so the text is not completely fitting inside the box

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/9spvfphw/)